# Reverse all words in current line

Tags: text-processing

I have a file and I want to reverse all word in it.

ex input file:

```
DCBA. HGFE.GI
MLK,PON.RQ
UTS. ZYXWV. 321
```

ex output file: (***What I Want***)

```
ABCD. EFGH.IG
KLM,NOP.QR
STU. VWXYZ. 123
```

With this sed script:  `sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'` all the entire line is reversed.

The wrong output produced by the command above:

```
IG.EFGH .ABCD    
QR.NOP,KLM    
123 .VWXYZ .STU
```

How can I get my desired output?

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence, it sounds like you don't want to reverse certain lines, but I can't tell which ones. Could you clarify?

Comment: There should be a `.` in his second line of input.

Comment: As it stands, this isn't going to work.  At the end of line one, you want to over-run into the next line.  At the end of line two, you want to assume an implied end of sentence.  To have it both ways is beyond text-processing, and requires a tool which understands grammar.

Comment: You didn't clarify your second sentence, but I think I get it now. Are all the "words" going to have spaces between them?

Comment: @Seth No it can be have no space between them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one in pure bash

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -N1 char; do
    if [[ "$char" =~ [[:alnum:]] ]]; then
        word="$char$word"
    else
        echo -n "$word$char"
        word=""
    fi
done <input.file >output.file
```

Output :

```
ABCD. EFGH.IG
KLM,NOP.QR
STU. VWXYZ. 123
```

This code logic is quite simple. We read the file character by character (thanks to the `-N1` flag. The `IFS=` is needed to be able to read newlines as well), then we add every valid character we encounter at the begining of the `$word` variable (thus reversing the word). When we encounter a non-alphanumeric character, we echo the value of `$word` and reset the value to empty. We repeat those steps until the end of the file

Comment: Glad it helped ;) I removed it when I updated my answer with `[[:alnum:]]`, as this is a special class that include also non-english characters

Comment: I'm surprised to read that the perl solution didn't work for non-English words. Under the hood, I would expect it and the bash solution to use almost identical sets of characters (perl's `\w` versus `[:alnum:]` should differ only by underscore). What is the output of `env | grep '^L\(C\|ANG\)'`?

Answer (score 4):

So, you really want to reverse each **word**, not each sentence, right? Or is your comma supposed to be a period?

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)/ reverse $1 /eg' << END
DCBA. HGFE.GI
MLK,PON.RQ
UTS. ZYXWV. 321
END
```

```
ABCD. EFGH.IG
KLM,NOP.QR
STU. VWXYZ. 123
```

If you want to redirect, do this:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)($|\W+)/ reverse($1) . $2 /eg' < file_in > file_out
```

With my example, do

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)($|\W+)/ reverse($1) . $2 /eg' << END > file_out
```

DO NOT put the redirection on the same line as the terminating word of the heredoc. If you do, the shell will not be able to find the end of the heredoc.

With redirecting to and from files, never do this: `command < file > file` with the same file. The redirections happen *before* the command starts, and `>` will truncate the file to zero length. When the command starts, the input file has already been destroyed.

Comment: @KasiyA simply use a redirection. On the last line, just write `END >output.file` (this is valid for other answers as well). Note that glenn's answer uses a heredoc (the `<<END ... END` syntax). If you have a real file, you should call his command like this : `perl -pe '... /eg'<input.file >output.file`

Comment: Don't put the redirection on the last line, use the first line. Explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

And the verbose (python) option:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open("/path/to/sourcefile") as messed_up:
    lines = [list(line.replace("\n", "")) for line in messed_up]

def reverse_line(l):
    i=0; line = ""; sep = (" ", ",",".")
    while i < len(l):
        word = []
        while not l[i] in sep:
            word.append(l[i]); i = i+1
            if i == len(l):
                line = line + ("").join(reversed(word)); break
        else:
            line = line + ("").join(reversed(word)) + l[i]
        i = i+1
    print(line)

for l in lines:
    reverse_line(l)
```

Outputs:

```
ABCD. EFGH.IG
KLM,NOP.QR
STU. VWXYZ. 123
```

Lines are "built up" from left to right; characters in the `sep` list (spaces, commas, dots or any other defined-) and single other characters are placed directly into the line, a consecutive number of other characters are collected first and reversed before they are added to the line.